# Sum of power series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!} x^{n}$

Tags: power-series

I am asked to find the sum function of the series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!} x^{n}$.
I know that $\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{n}$, but I dont know how to divide this series by $(2n+1)(2n+2)$

Help is appreciated!

Comment: It is more or less the series for $\cos x$ with some terms missing.

Comment: Relabel $n=m-1$  and your series for $\cos x$ is not quite right

Comment: You should have a $2n$ in the exponent of $x$ for your Maclaurin expansion for $\cos$

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you, I'm sorry for the mistake, I have been thinking about this problem for far too long :)

Comment: Please, do not change the question after receiving an answer. May I ask you to reedit the post with the orginal settings ? Thanks

Comment: I've reedited it back, sorry for messing that up, I'm quite new to this forum!

Comment: @SaimHQ. No problem ! If you want to address a comment to a user, start you message with *@username*. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

To make the two series "almost" similar, let $x=y^2$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!} y^{2n}=\frac 1 {y^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!} y^{2n+2}$$

Comment: The OP has edited the question so that it no longer has $x^n$ but $x^{2n}$ instead.

Comment: I think the argument still counts with no need for the substitution, but is the last realization that the series is $(cos(x) - 1)/x^2$?